# PHP left string concatenation operator?

Tags: php, string, operators, concatenation, string-concatenation

This might be a very simple and easy question to answer, perhaps not.

To concatenate a string (by appending/right concat.) in php you use:

```
$a = "a";

$a .= "b";
//The value will be: "ab"
```

**How do I do this, but the other way around?**

Ej.:

```
$a = "a";

$a ???? "b";
//I NEED the value to be: "ba"
```

Comment: What's wrong with $a="b".$a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to a built-in function would be using strpad like

```
$a = str_pad($a, strlen($a)+strlen("b"), "b", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

but as others have pointed out its much simpler to just do `$a = "b" . $a;`

Answer (score 9):

Use the standard concatenation operator; no special assignment operator exists.

```
$a = "b" . $a;
```

Answer (score 2):

$a = "b" . $a

No shorthand for it that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

what about `$ba = "b$a";` ? It will return `ba`!

When string are defined between double quotes, variables are parsed as strings automatically. By using single quotes the variable is not parsed instead! (`'b$a'` returns `b$a`).

If you the original string contains a special character that interferes with the variable' parsing, then you can enclose it between curly braces:

```php
echo "b_{$a}";  // returns: 'b_a'


// Recap

echo "b$a"; // => 'ba'

echo 'b$a'; // => 'b$a'
```

Double quotes plus curly braces (when required) are a very handy solution when you need to do many concatenations (e.g. an html tag with it's properties).